# Allowing class template's template parameters to be visible in the derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, class-template

I want to preserve visibility of a class template's parameter arguments when I inherit from it. The base class will have a large number of template arguments, so I don't want to keep asking for those in the derived class templates. Is the only way to do this with type aliases?

For example, this doesn't work, but it does if I swap everything out for the commented lines:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename one, typename of, typename very, typename many, typename tparams>
class first {
// public:
//  using A = one; //needs to be uncommented to work
};

template<typename class_instance>
class second : public class_instance {
    typename class_instance::one m_data;
    //typename class_instance::A m_data; // would work if we uncommented
};


int main() {

    second<first<int,int,int,int,int>> thing;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Basically, yes. The template parameter name is visible only in the template expansion. If you want it to be visible beyond that, you need to do that yourself (by creating a type alias for it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save kind of make it easier by using a variadic [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter).  Changing `second` to be

```
template<template<typename...> typename class_instance, typename... Params>
class second  {
public:
    template <std::size_t I>
    using param_t = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Params...>>;
    param_t<1> foo;
};
```

You can use it like

```
int main() {
    second<first, int, double, float, long, long long> foo{};
    foo.foo = 42.1;
    std::cout << foo.foo;
}
```

which outputs

```
42.1
```

as you can see in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b017997f75b6baa).

Yes, you are now using a number, which might not be worth it, but it removes a lot of the boiler plate.  If you really want you can even add an `enum` to `second` and use it like

```
template<template<typename...> typename class_instance, typename... Params>
class second  {
public:
    enum { one, of, very, many, tparams };
    template <std::size_t I>
    using param_t = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Params...>>;
    param_t<of> foo;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have a much better appreciation of what you can do with [tuples](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element)

Comment: @lakeweb No problem.  Tuples are used quite a bit in TMP.